# Yii2 Gridview Merge column on related table

Tags: gridview, yii2

Yii2 Gridview Merge column on related table:

i have this tables

```
Events
id
*idexpositor
```

.

```
Expositor
id
*idperson
```

-

```
Person
id
*name
*lastname
```

i'm creating a index view on Events and i need create a search filter to search a `name.' '.lastname`

i already create a function on Events model

```
public function getFullname()
{
    return ucwords(mb_strtolower($this->idexpositor0->idperson0->name.' '.$this->idexpositor0->idperson0->lastname));
}
```

i my index view i put this

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'id',
        'Nombrecompletoexpositor',

    ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

i can see fullname but i can't search. can any1 help? pls

Comment: Show your EventSearch model please

Comment: This has already been asked multiple times, you should read this http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#working-with-model-relations